# Need help turning a SQL query into an ActiveRecord query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following SQL code:

```
SELECT u.full_name, pu.task_name, sum(hours) 
FROM efforts
INNER JOIN project_tasks pu ON efforts.project_task_id = pu.id   
INNER JOIN users u ON efforts.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY user_id, task_name
```

Which outputs all users, their tasks and their hours. What I'm now trying to do is convert this to a Rails' ActiveRecord query.

I am trying to make it look similar to what I have done below but cannot seem to get my logic right.

```
    Project.all.each do |project|
      projdata = { 'name' => project.project_name.to_s,
                  'values' => [] }

    ['Pre-Sales','Project','Fault Fixing','Support'].each do |taskname|

     record = Effort.sum( :hours,
                          :joins => :project_task,
                           :conditions => { "project_tasks.project_id" => project.id,
                                         "project_tasks.task_name" => taskname } )             
        projdata[ 'values' ].push( record )
      end

      @data.push( projdata )
    end
  end
end
```

**Added image link**

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n19B.jpg)

The link illustrates a graph. What I need to do is convert my SQL statement into an activeRecord query which will display it like my other graph just as I supplied.

Comment: I want to turn the above SQL statement into RoR, so that when I implement this into highcharts it will display the all users their tasks and their hours

Comment: For that you need to show your ActiveRecord models, because from that the SQL is generated. But what is the real problem? What exactly is wrong? You need to be a bit more clear..

Comment: The SQL above works.... I need to get it "Ruby-fied" i need it to look like the code for the variable "record" above. e.g. Effort.sum...etc.

Comment: It seems you try to get the sum of hours spent on each task by each user, am I right ? because it's not really clear and i'm even surprised your SQL works (you should have something like SUM(hours)). Moreover your table names dont follow AR convention so it's hard to follow

Comment: @m_x your right thats what im trying to do , sorry its not that clear, i just thought considering it works in SQL it would be pretty easy to convert over... and i did have SUM(hours) but forgot to put it in..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.full_name, pu.task_name, hours 
FROM efforts
INNER JOIN project_tasks pu ON efforts.project_task_id = pu.id   
INNER JOIN users u ON efforts.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY user_id, task_name

Effort.find(:all, :select => "users.full_name, project_tasks.task_name, hours", :joins => [:user, :project_task], :group => "users.user_id, project_tasks.task_name")
```

But, I have one doubt, how can you get the "hours" field without adding it's on the grouping section. So, it's better, you can add the hours too in grouping section.

But, You should make some additional changes in the following file

vendor/plugins/expandjoinquery/init.rb’

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    private
    def add_joins!(sql, options, scope = :auto)
      scope = scope(:find) if :auto == scope
      join = (scope && scope[:joins]) || options[:joins]
      sql << " #{expand_join_query(join)} " if join
    end

    def expand_join_query(*joins)
      joins.flatten.map{|join|
        case join
        when Symbol
          ref = reflections[join] or
            raise ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError, "Could not find the source association :#{join} in model #{self}"
          case ref.macro
          when :belongs_to
            "INNER JOIN %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s" % [ref.table_name, ref.table_name, primary_key, table_name, ref.primary_key_name]
          else
            "INNER JOIN %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s" % [ref.table_name, ref.table_name, ref.primary_key_name, table_name, primary_key]
          end
        else
          join.to_s
        end
      }.join(" ")
    end
  end
end
```

Reference: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2119

My suggestion is,why should you use the eager loading with association names?.

Comment: Thanks but I need it similar to this format, I've edited your reply

Comment: it seems @Djj wants a sum of hours. I already had troubles trying to use group() and average() altogether, and ended up usingsomehing like `select("average(model.field), name").group("name")`,worked just fine. Wouldn't it be easier ?

Answer (score 0):

try something like :

```
Effort.joins(:project_tasks, :user).select("sum(hours) as total_hours, users.full_name, project_tasks.task_name").group("users.user_id, project_tasks.task_name")
```

Comment: `record = Effort.sum( :hours,
                          :joins => :project_task,
                           :conditions => { "project_tasks.project_id" => project.id,
                                         "project_tasks.task_name" => taskname } )             
        projdata[ 'values' ].push( record )
      end`  I need to it to look similar to this, so that I can then push all the data back to an array

Comment: then you may try adding something like `.collect(&:hours)` at the end of the chain (see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000247 fo collect() usage)

Comment: not sure if it works, but you might want to try this :

    Effort.sum(:hours, 
               :group => [:project_task_id, :user_id],
               :joins => [:project_task, :user])

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Effort.select(
   "users.full_name        full_name, 
    project_tasks.task_name       task_name, 
    SUM(efforts.hours) total_hours").
  joins(:project_task, :user).
  group("users.user_id, users.full_name, project_tasks.task_name").map do |e|
  puts e.full_name, e.task_name, e.total_hours
end
```